# IBM Watson IoT platform historical data connector for Cloudant

Tags: ibm-cloud, cloudant

I recently try to create a historical data connector to store the uploaded data in IBM Watson IoT Platform to IBM Cloudant. I have used the historical data storage extension APIs. However, I got the response

`{ "message": "CUDSS0026E: The supplied service credentials are not valid.", "exception": { "id": "CUDSS0026E", "properties": [] } }`

I have checked that I typed the correct service credential from Cloudant service.
Does anyone meet the same problem or know the answer about this?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps I am late, but I have solved right now this issue:

1. Create a Cloudant service and set identification: IAM and Legacy.
2. Click on the new Cloudant instance.
3. Go to Service Credentials and create a new credential.
4. Copy it.
5. Go to IoT Swagger UI, Autorize to run commands, and in Service->Post, click  and use the following JSON:
   {
   "name": "whatever-you-like", "type": "cloudant",
   "credentials":  < add your credentials from the Cloudant, point 4 >
   }

The issue is that the HTTP API understands only Legacy identification.

Kind regards.